# SMS reminder for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, sms

A lot of mobile phones can be setup to emit a reminder beep every few minutes if you have an unread SMS. If you miss the receive signal of the SMS (for example, if you've been in the restroom) you'll hear a gentle beep every few minutes, so that you know you received an SMS while you've been busy.

Is there a way to get this behaviour on Windows Mobile 6.5?

I found nothing to activate this in the menu, but maybe it's hidden somewhere. Perhaps I need some additional software to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need extra software.  I had a program on my old SDA that I used, but I haven't used that phone in years so I don't remember what piece of software that was.  You can try [Missed Call Reminder](http://www.wm6software.net/utilities/missed_call_reminder.html/).

Answer (score 1):

Try [DontForget](http://magazin.softimage.cz/dontforget/download/), which is free.

I installed it on my Samsung Omnia Pro B7320 (Windows Mobile 6.5 ) and it worked normally except for the vibrating alert feature (related to the profile I used).

You can find additional features in the options.